# PGSQL/Java - Inserting data to different tables dynamically

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, prepared-statement, sql-insert

So, I'm trying to insert data to a database completely dynamically, meaning the data will be inserted without any knowledge of what table we're inserting into. The same goes for the different attributes.

My problem is that for some reason, my table names get wrapped in '' when preparing the statment. It goes as follows:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO ? VALUES(?)";
try{
    Connection conn = Connection.create();
    PreparedStatment st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    st.setString(1, "test");
    st.setString(2, "1");
    st.addBatch();
//... (executes batch later on...)
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(rs);
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
}
```

Now for some reason, and completely beyond me, if I print this statement I get:

```
"INSERT INTO 'test' VALUES("1");
```

while I would expect

```
"INSERT INTO test VALUES("1");
```

Could anyone explain why this happens and how I can solve this, or a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? If it matters I'm using DbUtils to handle closing, and 3CP0 for connection pooling.

I have been looking all over without any luck. And I would also appreciate it if anyone could tell me if inserting data dynamically to different tables generally is a bad thing.

Comment: You can't use a parameter for the table name - you'll have to use string concatenation for that part.  That, of course, opens you up to SQL injection, unless you have some way of validating the table names.  Frankly, I would design this differently - can you merge all the tables into one?

Comment: Oh, okay, so that's why. I've tried string concatenation as well but it seemed to me that I got the same problem there as well.  I guess I'll have to look at it again and see if I can approach my problem from a different angle.